# MeteorJs getting querystring data for templatehelper use

Tags: meteor, query-string

I am new to Meteor and have a slight problem with Meteor. 
I created a link which is
http://localhost:3000/game?id=7lJ8F
how would I get the id value in the query string and return it to a helper.
I have looked for answers but found none.

```
Router.route('/game/:_id', function(){
    Session.set("gameid",this.params.query.id);

  });
  Template.gamebefore.helpers({
    ids: function () {
      return Session.get("gameid");
    }
  });
```

I know this is all wrong but I am quite desperate to find an answer so any will help. Thank You!

Comment: try with `Session.set("gameid",this.params._id);`

Answer (score 0):

How to handle and get the parameters of an url are described in the [guide of iron router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters)

You might miss the _:

```
this.params.query.id
```

should be

```
this.params.query._id
```

or vice versa, since in your url is

```
/game?id=7lJ8F
```

in your route its

```
Router.route('/game/:_id', function(){
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need an id in the route:

```
Router.route('/game', function(){
    Session.set("gameid",this.params.query.id);

  });
  Template.gamebefore.helpers({
    ids: function () {
      return Session.get("gameid");
    }
  });
```

As a note, instead of using `http://..../game?id=somegameid`, you might want to use a more REST approach by using `http://.../game/somegameid`, in which case, you need this route:

```
Router.route('/game/:_id', function(){
    Session.set("gameid",this.params._id);

  });
  Template.gamebefore.helpers({
    ids: function () {
      return Session.get("gameid");
    }
  });
```